# T-SQL Error in non-executing branch of if..else block

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm hitting my head against the wall with this one.

We have a stored procedure that is being called in an API that we are developing and the stored procedure has the following code:

```
if(@StatusCode = 41 and @OperationName != 'convert')
Begin
    EXEC [uspCreateOrg] @RequestID = @_RequestId
End
else
Begin
    EXEC [uspUpsertOrg] @RequestID = @_RequestId
End
```

Using the profiler, we can that the 'if' branch is the one that gets executed, but we also see that SQL Server is looking down the 'else' branch and calling into that stored procedure and throwing an exception.  The uspUpsertOrg procedure calls the DBAmp BulkOps which has the following code in it:

```
create table #errorlog (line varchar(255))
insert into #errorlog
exec @Result = master..xp_cmdshell @Command

-- print output to msgs
declare @line varchar(255)
declare @printCount int
set @printCount = 0
DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT line FROM #errorlog
OPEN tables_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @line
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
   if @line is not null
   begin
      print @line 
      exec SF_Logger @SPName,N'Message', @Line
      set @errorLines = @errorLines + @line
      set @printCount = @printCount +1  
   end
   FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @line
END
deallocate tables_cursor

-- drop temp output table
drop table #errorlog
```

The exception that gets thrown is that the #errorLog table does not exist.  So in summary we are getting an exception that a temp table created on the line above the insert does not exist in a stored procedure that does not even get called...Fun...

When we comment out the call to uspUpsertOrg everything works as expected.  When we change the temp table to a real table, it still fails, but if we create it outside the procedure and then run the process, it works.  In any of these cases, the code does not go down the 'else' branch in the sense that the 'else' branch would be the one that gets executed.  It's almost as if SQL server is looking ahead down all code paths--I know that SQL Server does that kind of thing for optimization, etc, but why would it miss the fact that the table IS being created before use?  I've done this kind of thing before and never had problems.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are you encountering this error?  When executed from SSMS?  Or is this error being encountered when called from the front end?  If from the front end, can you provide how it's being called?

Comment: Does your application try to retrieve metadata about the stored procedure's result set? e.g. with `SET FMTONLY ON;` then executing it?

Comment: @Kritner The initial stored procedure is being called from BizTalk, but unfortunately I don't know more than that.  In the profiler I can see the username and sessionId.

Comment: @MartinSmith The application is not retrieving metadata.

Comment: I see you mention Biztalk - Does this apply? http://geekswithblogs.net/edmundzhao/archive/2011/09/04/146765.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith that's what I was thinking as well.  Some of .net dataset type objects can't handle temporary tables within procs.  Replacing the temp tables with variable tables seems to do the trick though

Comment: Amazing! What a relief! I wrapped the offending DBAmp call with SET FMTONLY OFF and it now works.  Not the easiest thing to Google either so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to this article on [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/), this exact scenario causes a problem for the `algebrizer` that doesn't execute your code, but is responsible for generating the execution plan.  Look for the section *When the Estimated Plan is Invalid*.

I think this workaround will work for you:  Instead of the `CREATE` statement, use

```
SELECT CAST('' as VARCHAR(255)) as line INTO #errorlog
```